# Why doesn't css-calc() work when using 0 inside the equation?

Tags: css, equation, css-calc

I'm using `calc()` to set the `top:` attribute in a class.  I need some help understanding how `calc()` gets used - two equations I believe should have the same result don't.  (The top equation isn't practical, I'm just trying to debug a larger issue and noticed these two don't have the same result)

```
calc(-10px + ((1 - 1) * 0));

calc(-10px);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first equation is invalid because it will lead to `calc(-10px + 0)`

> Note: Because `<number-token>`s are always interpreted as `<number>`s or `<integer>`s, "unitless 0" `<length>`s aren’t supported in `calc()`. That is, width: `calc(0 + 5px);` is invalid, even though both width: 0; and width: 5px; are valid. <sup>[ref](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-3/#calc-type-checking)</sup>

And if the result was non-zero you will fall into this:

> At + or -, check that **both sides have the same type**, or that one side is a **`<number>` and the other is an `<integer>`**. If both sides are the same type, resolve to that type. If one side is a `<number>` and the other is an `<integer>`, resolve to `<number>`.

The last one is more logical since `10px + 5` has no meaning whearas we may think that `10px + 0` is simply `10px` but for the browser it's not.

Related question: [Why doesn't min() (or max()) work with unitless 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62520998/8620333)

Comment: That makes sense, thanks!  My follow up question: how do I need to reformat ```top: calc(-10px - (100% - 627px));``` to be valid/usable?

Comment: @nbixler it seems valid for me since your are using a mix of % and px that can work together

Comment: Update: Started working when I switched from % to vw (I know they aren't interchangeable, so I had to reconfigure my equation a bit).

Comment: @nbixler I forget something ... % with px should work BUT there is another issue which is that top value using % will not work if the parent element don't have a height set. So calc is valid but the issue is somewhere else. You can test the % without calc and you will face the same thing